# Change protocol from http to https under the same domain but different port

Tags: javascript, https, network-protocols

I'm trying to have a link in my nav bar that redirects the user from the main site (hosted on port 80 using http) to a control panel that uses https on a custom port (eg 9876). I have the link:

`<a href="/" onclick="javascript:event.target.port=9876">My CP</a>`

Which gets me to the correct port, but how do I get it to change protocol? Is there a link or site that lists the API for the event.target?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

`<a href="/" onclick="javascript:event.target.port=9876;event.target.protocol='https:';">My CP</a>`

Simple enough. Does anyone know a better or more elegant way of doing this? Also my question about the API still stands.

Thanks!